# Magento How to remove Black image from Image backgrounds

Tags: magento

I'm new to Magento. I was so confused with the images used in magento. I have changed the default image size 135x135 in product lists to 300X400. But now the problem is, the exact product page image is having black background image & while inspect element it's showing the size as 267x267.

Plz explain me. I want the image size in

1. product page as 300X400
2. Inner exact product image as 300X400
3. Also i'm using zoom effect extension. The image should not get pixelate while onhover. So what is the image size should i use while upload product image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the below code

```
echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->constrainOnly(true)->keepAspectRatio(true)->keepFrame(false)->resize(300, null)
```

This code will resize the image without affect the image ratio. If you gave fixed width and height the resize image will lose the originality.

Answer (score 0):

I found a comment in Magento community. To fix the black background
go to `GD2.php` and after the **line 301** :

```
$this->_fillBackgroundColor($newImage);
```

put this code:

```
$whitebg=imagecolorallocate($newImage,255,255,255);
imagefilledrectangle($newImage,0,0,$frameWidth,$frameHeight,$whitebg);
```

ready!

Answer (score -1):

Solution:

```
<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->keepTransparency(false); ?>
```